# Trouble with assigning backslash in a string in R

Tags: r, string, cat, backslash

I am having trouble to assign a string character to an object containing a backslash on it in R. The idea is that I want to produce an output to Latex, so there are characters such as "{" on my output.

Suppose you have a list with two numbers on it:

```
list1 <- list()
list1[[1]] <- 0.166
list1[[2]] <- 0.232
```

I want to concatenate them like this (assigning to an object):

```
x <- NULL
for (i in 1:2) {
  x <- c(x,paste0("{",list1[[i]],"}"))
}
```

In this case I have the following output: `"{0.166}" "{0.232}"`

But I want to have this for Latex readability: `"\{0.166\}" "\{0.232\}"`

I cannot simply add the "\" to the string, so I tried using "\\", but it prints the two bars and not just one.

I also tried using the `cat()` function, which seems to work:

```
x <- NULL
for (i in 1:2) {
  x <- c(x,cat("\\","{",list1[[i]],"\\","}",sep=""))
}
x
```

But here I have two issues: first it just prints the output, it does not store it to my object. The printed output is: `\{0.166\}\{0.232\}`

I tried using `capture.output()` but the result is again with two bars: `"\\{0.166\\}" "\\{0.232\\}"`

The second issue is that I need each number separated and the output with cat seems to put everything together.

Can someone help me with that?

Comment: Do you need `paste0("\\","{",list1,"\\","}")` ?

Comment: `I tried using "\\", but it prints the two bars and not just one`: Using `"\\"` is correct, it's just that when you `print`, R shows the \ escaped. The string actually just contains \, which is what you see when you `cat` it.

Comment: @Marius your hint made me solve the question by generating output to a .tex file instead. Should I post an answer?